# best possible schema design for log analysis database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have to store the following data in mongodb `uid, gender ,country, city, date_of_visit, url_of_visit`

I would like to store uid, gender, country and city in one collection because these information will never change for particular user.

in the other collection i would like to store `uid, date_of_visit, url_of_visit`

i want to know which is best practice to store `uid, date_of_visit and url_of_visit`.there are two things in my mind..

```
    (a) { uid: 100, date: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, url: abc.php }
        { uid: 100, date: xxxxxx, url: ref.php }
        { uid: 200, date: xxxxxxxxx, url: ref.php } 

    (b) { uid:100, visit:[{date:xxxxxxx, url:abc.php},
                          {date:xxxx, url:def.php},
                          {.........................}]}
```

i want to have following index date:1, uid:1 ,url:1 ...the problem with approach (a) is with each row inserted in database the database side and index size will grow and there will come a point when index size will not fit into RAM

problem with approach (b) is at some point each document will exceed the 16 MB limit and this approach will fail that time..

please suggest me what should be the best schema design for this scenario. i would also have the query which include `uid, gender, country, date_of_visit, url_of_visit`

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit older but I'm wondering if you've decided on a structure and if it works well.

My idea was, instead of risking to create too large documents, to structure it similar to your second approach but include the date in the main collection. This way each document would be the user's activity within one day. It would be indexed by user and date, easy to update and query and keep things organized.

Something like:

```
{ uid:100, date:xxxxxxx, event:[{time:xxxxxxx, url:abc.php},
                                {time:xxxx, url:def.php},
                                {.........................}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach is better than one because it corresponds to idea of grouping similar data together. About exceeding 16M of document you can reach this limit but he should be a very active user. :)

Also you can pull out some data to another collection and make reference using ObjectId or DBRef. 
See more info http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef

Comment: one question out of curiosity :) . With time the document size will grow then will the write operations on those documents ( documents with larger size) will be slow?

Comment: It's hard to say and it depends on amount of total Mongo data and how it fits in memory. But I think it's ok because in other case the limit will be 8M like in previous version.

Comment: I want to covert Uid to Bin Data and assign it to _id field. is it good idea to make uid as _id ? I have read in documentation that "Use _id values that are roughly in ascending order." and my uids value are totally random

Comment: I'd prefer don't change _id and create Unique Indexes on UID

Comment: okay. I think uid:1, date:-1 index will work better for most of the queries because our main interest will be in the recently active users :)

Comment: Do you want to use query with filtering by date? In this case you should create index visit.date:1 for the second variant and date:1 for the first.

Comment: hello i want to have index like this .. db.logs.ensureIndex({uid:1, visit.date:1}) ....actually i want to have index on both uid and visit.date ...for index on uid i wanted to replace _id with uid(my uids bigint type and totally random) as per your advice i have drooped the idea of replacing _id with uid, so are uid:1, visit.date:1 right index? some times i want to have range queries on date(for daily, weekly and monthly active users) and some times i will use both uid and date

Comment: Yes, in this case {uid:1, visit.date:1} is proper index.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach will force you to fetch a huge amount of data from the embedded document, which cannot be filtered by Mongo. In other words, if you have a million documents stored inside the "event" field for a particular user, then when you fetch those embedded documents with dot notation, then the entire document including the parent will be returned.  There's no way you can filter the results.

I would recommend the first approach which makes the data easier to retrieve and work with.